# Image acquisition hardware scanning from Java

Tags: java, image-processing, image-scanner

How can I implement image acquisition from hardware scanner in Windows? I found [JTwain](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/)  library, but it's commercial. Is there any free frameworks? Any information about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an [article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/11/18/twain.html) discussing how to implement your own API using TWAIN (confusingly also called JTwain).

From the article:

> Java's lack of a standard
>   image-acquisition API is an oversight
>   that hopefully will be rectified in a
>   future release. Until that time,
>   however, we can either purchase a
>   commercial API or create our own API.
>
> We can base our API on either of the
>   TWAIN or SANE specifications. So far,
>   we've only looked at TWAIN, in terms
>   of the big picture and important
>   details. We have also explored the
>   very simple TWAIN-based JTwain API and
>   played with a simple JTwainDemo
>   application that demonstrates JTwain.

Comment: At first look it doesn't work with my scanner. It actually does not perform scan, but displays old image from scanner's cache.
But anyway thanks for answer, I'll look in this direction.

Answer (score 3):

If it's for personal or educational use, maybe you can use Morena: http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html

Unfortunetely, if it's for commercial use you will have to pay for it.

Comment: I need it for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

There is EZTwain, which I was coding from jni and getting objects ( actual java objects that showed up and were usable in Java on the Java side after being constructed with all that L stuff. Never got past the dib struct pointers ... ended up looking the fool in front of Spike ( he was a true professional about it ) and before I could get the dib stuff within comprehension I crashed Whino the Poo at the root and lost data-up-link to the wooly-web and as well had to go to work in a factory to meet needs.

I'm sure I salvaged much of the code as I was digging around in the data-recovery stuff I did where I saved the "D" work that I was beginning. I had intended to do an ocr character recognition as I have a statewide organization with hundreds of real people doing legitimate work and the central office is bogged by primitive data entry methods that would never scale to the volume that is just down the road.

The license for EZTwain is well implemented as it takes much of the commercial territory as reserved for their legitimate commercial turf. I really think it would be funny as an interview question to discuss Sarbanes-Oxley auditor independence as a function of Gaussian kernel radius in the Canny edge detection algorithm.  ( in Java - Tom Gibara )

I'm sure they would ask me the "O" of the thing, I'd say "Oh!"

Which is about what you would say after a few hundred func names in JNI.

( not trying to be funny, it's just that this is why you don't see a lot of development in this area )